# RestTemplate messageConverters

Tags: resttemplate, jackson-dataformat-xml

Is there a way to force `RestTemplate` to use a certain `HttpMessageConverter` for a specific message ?

For some reason, I send an object as payload, and even though the annotation are `Json`'s (`@JsonCreator`, `@JsonProperty`...) it uses `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` to serialize this object to XML.

Comment: Did you set `Content-Type` header to `application/json`?

Comment: @MichalFoksa no, obviously. but I rather use `postForObject()` with my objects, and not `HttpEntity`. is it possible ?

Comment: Can you PLS post your client code?

Comment: @MichalFoksa. there you go.
`Response<EmptyData> response = restClient.postForObject("https://" + deviceIP + "/jsonrpc", loginRequest,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<EmptyData>>() {});`

Comment: `loginRequest` is a ParameterizedType with `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` @nnotations.

Answer (score 1):

Change to restClient.exchange and set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in order to explicitly request response in JSON.

```
LoginRequestType<XXXX> loginRequest;
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<LoginRequestType<XXXX>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<LoginRequestType<XXXX>>(loginRequest,headers);

Response<EmptyData> response = restClient
    .exchange("https://" + deviceIP + "/jsonrpc", 
        HttpMethod.POST, 
        requestEntity, 
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<EmptyData>>(){}).getBody();
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid... I'm writing a wrapper to RestTemplate and I want to avoid another `MediaType` argument. probably impossible.

Comment: Maybe you can avoid using `@Json....` annotations. In that case your entities will be more independent.

Comment: My entities aren't real application entities, these are just POJOs I create to put as payloads for REST requests...

Comment: I see. Good luck then :)